# predefined sections to mute in html5 audio

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

newbie in front end dev.
I've managed to use audio tag - really cool.

My need is to mute parts of the .wav that are predefined (for example mute between second 3 to second 8, and from second 32 to second 41) - meaning that if the user will listen to the wav, once getting to the configured sections - won't hear anything.

Is there a way to do it? or cannot be done?

Answer (score 0):

Using .wav is not the most crossbrowser friendly, but it is possible to do what you want to do by monitoring the `timeupdate` event and when it reaches the time you want, e.g. 3 seconds, set the video's `mute` value to true, and then change it to false when it reaches 8 seconds.